# C# MVC - Dynamic database architecture

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have an idea for a web app where I will want the user to create their own database through a web application, with their own table names and field types.

I thought about creating a database structure using Object Oriented Programming so that a pre-made database will support all kinds of Entities with custom properties. Something like this:

```cs
CustomType
{
    public long TypeId {get;set;} 
    public string ActiveType {get;set;}
}

CustomProperty
{
    public int wholeNumber {get;set;}
    public string text {get;set;}
    public bool boolean {get;set;}
    public decimal dec {get;set;}

    //Choosen Id of the type to work with
    public long TypeId {get;set;}

    public bool wholeNumber_ACTIVE {get;set;}
    public bool text_ACTIVE {get;set;}
    public bool boolean_ACTIVE {get;set;}
    public bool dec_ACTIVE {get;set;} 
}

CustomEntity
{
    public string TableName {get;set;}
    public CustomProperty Prop01 {get;set;}
    public CustomProperty Prop02 {get;set;}
    public CustomProperty Prop03 {get;set;}
    public CustomProperty Prop04 {get;set;}
    public CustomProperty Prop05 {get;set;}
}
```

The idea behind this is to let the user decide what they want their database to store, on a pre-made database for them to work with, without having to create it during runtime since this is a web app.

I believe I can manage it like this for them to store whatever they need, but I'm also thinking about the following issues:

1. How will I manage relationships when the user needs to link tables with Ids and foreign keys.
   (I though about managing a `public long ForeignId {get;set;}` and just store the Id they need to associate).
2. How will I manage queries since tables will have CodeNames and each will have a different meaning for each person that sets it up.
   (I though about, renaming the table during Runtime, but I'm afraid of errors and DB corruption).
3. Also thought about sending direct queries to create the database according to user's need, but then again non-experienced users can really mess up here or find it hard to manage.
4. How can I manage migration or DB changes with code instead of the use of PowerShell console.
5. If we have multiple users each with a unique database, but the same web app how can we manage webconfigs to work with this idea.

I know there's a lot of questions here, I'm looking for the best way to achieve this, having multiple users own their small web app through the internet using MVC pattern and lots of options through a browser.

Comment: What are you using for your database as a library? EF? EF Core? Or what. Maybe you're going to manage it all via any other library? Please, clarify.

Comment: You are right, I forgot this detail. I'm using EF to use LinQ for my db management into the SQL.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this but you can use Reflection and rebuild the model probably.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an [Entity Attribute Value (EAV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) pattern as a solution. With the EAV pattern, rather than creating new tables with new columns for every custom property you wish to store, you store those properties in rows. For example. Instead of every custom table being defined like this:

[image]

You define them like this instead:

[image]

This allows for flexible creation of multiple entities with multiple properties. The classes in your business logic will then be Entity classes with a collection of Property objects.

In case you haven’t spotted the trade-offs already, the limitation of using the EAV model is the inability to specify field types (int, varchar, decimal etc.), infact, all your property values will be stored as a single type (usually strings).

There are a number of ways to address this. Some handle all the validation etc. in the business logic, other create Field tables per type, so based on my example, rather than having just one EntityFields table, you’ll have multiple, separated by type.